# Rails 3 Nested Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have very interesting scenario:

I've specified two controllers, one for global events and another another once for company specific events.  In routes, it is specified like this:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :events
end
resources: events
```

Running rake routes I can see the routes being generated:

```
events GET  /events(.:format) events#index
company_events GET /companies/:company_id/events(.:format) events#index
```

Both paths seem to route to the same controller (the global one)...
I have the second controller under controller/companies that goes something like this:

```
class Companies::EventsController < ApplicationController
 # stuff
end
```

It never routes in that controller above, no matter whether I use company_evens_path(@company). always goes to the other one.
It used to work in rails 2.3 for me, I'm currently using 3.2

Comment: Are you sure you need a separate controller, seems like to keep it dry you should just throw an if params[:company_id] in the index action of the global events controller to show only those events.

Comment: This is working as expected, according to your routes.  Both route to the EventsController and the index method.  If you need different behavior based on which route is followed, you can do that from a single controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as stated above, I would recommend doing something like this:

```
def index
  if params[:company_id]
    @events = Company.find(params[:company_id]).events
  else
    @events = Events.all
  end
end
```

although if you need to you can specify a controller:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :events, :controller => "companies/events"
end
resources: events
```

and just create a companies folder inside your controllers folder to put your Companies::EventsController inside

Comment: Here are the docs for more info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to do this if I wouldn't find other solution.  And that will force me to manually render templates in the controller, that's quite... hmm.

Comment: ohh, ya hmm didn't think about that, you could just put your templates in the shared folder and then link to the same partials

Comment: and not to beat a dead horse, but i'd just let the single events controller give you back the specific collection of events youre looking for, and all the other logic throw in helper to keep the controller clean

Comment: also you won't have to manually render the templates, they will just match up with views in the views/companies/events folder instead of the views/events folder